# Unable to implement date range filter in elastic search using query

Tags: date, curl, elasticsearch, filter, range

when I am executing below query using curl

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash*/_search' -d '{ "query" : { "filter" : [  "range" : { "timestamp" : {"gt" : "2017-02-01 00:00:00","lt" : "2017-05-01 00:00:00"}}]}}'
```

I am getting below error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[filter] query malformed, no start_object after query name","line":1,"col":26}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[filter] query malformed, no start_object after query name","line":1,"col":26},"status":400}
```

But if I am executing the date range filter with above query from sense plugin, it is running fine.

Elastic version 5.2

Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change your query to this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash*/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gt": "2017-02-01 00:00:00",
            "lt": "2017-05-01 00:00:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks val, it worked...My query also worked ....actually the problem was with the timestamp format...

Comment: The initial problem was due to the fact that your query was malformed. Then effectively, you might have had another issue with the date format.